# Emacs: shell commands on multiple files - how to refer to the actual file in the script?

Tags: file, shell, variables, scripting, emacs

Lets say I have a group of (text) files in Emacs, either by

- marking them in Dired  or by
- making a fileset

Then I want to call a shell script on all the files in the group. Easy enough. But in the script, I have a command that takes a file as argument like this:

foo(file)

Since the looping over the group of files is conveniently done by Emacs, I would need a kind of shell variable that refers to the file that is processed at the moment, something like:

$file = {the file that is processed at the moment}

foo($file)

But how do I get a reference to the processed file? I would probably need the absolute path.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are doing operations on multiple files in the shell. I would recommend saving the list of filenames into a file and then use the command `xargs` to operate on the files.

So for example to run `doit.sh` on all the filenames saved in the file `filelist` the command would be:

```
$ xargs -n 1 doit.sh < filelist
```

In the file `doit.sh` the current file is `$1`.